# How to simplify this two JS function coding?

Tags: javascript

Background: Below coding work fine, and i am able to use both function and return the expected value.

Question: Is there any way to simplify below function coding?

```
  red_messages_disabled_p1() {
    let s = this.status;
    if (s.red_messages[0] === null) {
        return 'none';
      } else {
        return 'inline-block';
      }
  },

  red_messages_disabled_p2() {
    let s = this.status;
    if (s.red_messages[1] === null) {
        return 'none';
      } else {
        return 'inline-block';
      }
  },
```

What did I try?
I tried to figure it out but no idea, guessing it's not possbile to simplify any more, am i correct?

Expecting?
I expecting there maybe simplify way for this coding.

Answer (score 3):

First option :

```
red_messages_disabled_p(i) {
  return this.status.red_messages[i-1] === null ? 'none' : 'inline-block';
}
```

Second option :

```
red_messages_disabled_p(i) {
  return this.status.red_messages[i-1] ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
}
```

Comment: You thought the same as me.

Comment: You can simplify this further by replacing `s.red_messages[i]` with `this.status.red_messages[i]`. There's no need to create a new variable.

Comment: @Michael M Nice idea

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of code duplication. Both of your functions contain  the same logic. So move that logic into a separate method as shown below:

```js
class MyClass {
    status = {red_messages: []}

    redMsgDisplayStyle(msg) {
        if (msg === null) {
            return 'none';
        }
        return 'inline-block';
    }

    red_messages_disabled_p1() {
        return this.redMsgDisplayStyle(this.status.red_messages[0])
    }

    red_messages_disabled_p2() {
        return this.redMsgDisplayStyle(this.status.red_messages[1])
    }
}
```

This will not only simplify the code, but also make it less error prone in case of you decide to change the logic in the future.

Also, replacing `if-else` with a ternary operator is probably not a good idea because: 1) it doesn't actually simplify the logic, just a different syntax and 2) ternary operator is less readable.

Answer (score 1):

Use a ternary operator

```
red_messages_disabled_p1() {
  let s = this.status;
  return s.red_messages[0] === null ? 'none' : 'inline-block';
}

red_messages_disabled_p2() {
  let s = this.status;
  return s.red_messages[1] === null ? 'none' : 'inline-block';
}
```

Comment: Two functions are same except parameters.

Answer (score 0):

use a parameterized function

```
red_messages_disabled(index) {
  let s = this.status;
  if (s.red_messages[index] === null) {
    return 'none';
  } else {
    return 'inline-block';
  }
}

red_messages_disabled_p1() {
  return this.red_messages_disabled(0);
};

red_messages_disabled_p2() {
  return this.red_messages_disabled(1);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already lots of good answers for this question, but I wanted to submit my own solution.

```js
const redMessageDisabled => (index) {
    return (s.red_messages[index] === null)?"none":"inline-block";
}
```

However, I think you can just pass `s.red_messages[index]` to the function

```js
const redMessageDisabled => (data) {
    return (data === null) ? "none" : "inline-block";
}
```